# Conditionally replacing a substring value in a column with substrings of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, substring

Let's say you have the following simple dataframe:

```
Input <- c("X0_1-2 + X1_1-2","X0_1-2 + X1_1-2","X0_1-3 + X1_1-3","X0_3-2 + X1_3-2","X0_3-1 + X1_3-1","X0_2-1 + X1_2-1","X0_2-3 + X1_2-3","X0_13-1 + X1_13-1")
State1 <- c("1-3","1-3","1-2","3-1","3-2","2-1","2-1","13-3")
State2 <- c("1-2","1-2","1-3","3-2","3-1","2-3","2-3","13-1")
DataFrame <- cbind(Input,State1,State2)
DataFrame <- as.data.frame(DataFrame)
```

Yielding

```
            Input State1 State2
1 X0_1-2 + X1_1-2    1-3    1-2
2 X0_1-2 + X1_1-2    1-3    1-2
3 X0_1-3 + X1_1-3    1-2    1-3
4 X0_3-2 + X1_3-2    3-1    3-2
5 X0_3-1 + X1_3-1    3-2    3-1
6 X0_2-1 + X1_2-1    2-1    2-3
7 X0_2-3 + X1_2-3    2-1    2-3
8 X0_13-1 + X1_13-1  13-3   13-1
```

I have tried to come up with a smart way to add an extra column equal to the "Input" column, but such that the values following the "_"
are either those of State1 or State2, according to which is different from the corresponding substring in Input, i.e, in this case the desired outcome is

```
            Input State1 State2          Outcome
1 X0_1-2 + X1_1-2    1-3    1-2 X0_1-3 + X1_1-3
2 X0_1-2 + X1_1-2    1-3    1-2 X0_1-3 + X1_1-3
3 X0_1-3 + X1_1-3    1-2    1-3 X0_1-2 + X1_1-2
4 X0_3-2 + X1_3-2    3-1    3-2 X0_3-1 + X1_3-1
5 X0_3-1 + X1_3-1    3-2    3-1 X0_3-2 + X1_3-2
6 X0_2-1 + X1_2-1    2-1    2-3 X0_2-3 + X1_2-3
7 X0_2-3 + X1_2-3    2-1    2-3 X0_2-1 + X1_2-1
8 X0_13-1 + X1_13-1  13-3    13-1 X0_13-3 + X1_13-3
```

But have been unsuccessful thus far.

**The idea is to replace whatever comes after the _ in the Input field, on both sides of the sum, with either the value of State1 or State2, whichever is different.**

Any ideas/input would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this, Assuming df is your dataframe:

```
replacement <- c("State2","State1")[mapply(grepl, df$State2, df$Input)+1]
df$output <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i)gsub( "\\d+-\\d+",df[i, replacement[i]],df[i,"Input"]))
```

**Output**:

```
> df
            Input State1 State2          output
1 X0_1-2 + X1_1-2    1-3    1-2 X0_1-3 + X1_1-3
2 X0_1-2 + X1_1-2    1-3    1-2 X0_1-3 + X1_1-3
3 X0_1-3 + X1_1-3    1-2    1-3 X0_1-2 + X1_1-2
4 X0_3-2 + X1_3-2    3-1    3-2 X0_3-1 + X1_3-1
5 X0_3-1 + X1_3-1    3-2    3-1 X0_3-2 + X1_3-2
6 X0_2-1 + X1_2-1    2-1    2-3 X0_2-3 + X1_2-3
7 X0_2-3 + X1_2-3    2-1    2-3 X0_2-1 + X1_2-1
8 X0_2-1 + X1_2-1    2-3    2-1 X0_2-3 + X1_2-3
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the state expressed by `Input` and `Outcome` is the same for both the `"XO"` and the `"X1"` portion of the string. Also `State1` and `State2` are never the same. In this case, you can pull out the state from input, compare it to one of the two states, and paste together your output string thus:

```
output <- ifelse(substring(DataFrame$Input, 13) == State1, State2, State1)
DataFrame$Outcome <- paste("X0_", output, " + X1_", output, sep = "")
DataFrame
#               Input State1 State2           Outcome
# 1   X0_1-2 + X1_1-2    1-3    1-2   X0_1-3 + X1_1-3
# 2   X0_1-2 + X1_1-2    1-3    1-2   X0_1-3 + X1_1-3
# 3   X0_1-3 + X1_1-3    1-2    1-3   X0_1-2 + X1_1-2
# 4   X0_3-2 + X1_3-2    3-1    3-2   X0_3-1 + X1_3-1
# 5   X0_3-1 + X1_3-1    3-2    3-1   X0_3-2 + X1_3-2
# 6   X0_2-1 + X1_2-1    2-1    2-3   X0_2-3 + X1_2-3
# 7   X0_2-3 + X1_2-3    2-1    2-3   X0_2-1 + X1_2-1
# 8 X0_13-1 + X1_13-1   13-3   13-1 X0_13-3 + X1_13-3
```

This solution will work for any length of "state" substring (e.g., both `"1-1" and "201-14") expressed by the`Input` variable.  You could use regex, but in this case, extracting based on position works (and is more efficient).

Comment: Looks gr8, thanks! Without wanting to be pushy, can you think of a way of making the substring handle larger arguments? Just in case there may be the need to have an "Input" in the format   X13_13-1 or something, and not having to go case by case...

Comment: @Arrebimbomalho I'm not sure I understand the new question. Maybe write it up as a new question, with examples of the behavior you're looking for, and we'll see if I can answer.

Comment: So, a way of conditionally replacing everything that come after the _ in "Input" without considering the length would be good...

Comment: @Arrebimbomalho ok, it will now work for any length state substring.  Because `substring` (vs. it's partner `substr`) extracts all the way to the end of the `text` argument when not given a `last` argument, we just pull from the end. I also fixed a potential problem in my original code, by changing the `text` argument for `substring` to `DataFrame$Input` instead of just `Input`. This way if you do any manipulation of the data frame (or if you didn't generate it in the manner you show us in your question), you're pulling it from the data frame instead of the initial variable.

Comment: Gr8, thanks! In any case I edited the original question in case someone else feels brave enough to chime in :)